# Can a registration fee credit towards a future event be recorded in Civi?

Tags: civievent, contributions

Civi Version 5.19.4, Drupal.
We run two (in person) conference/trade show events each year.  Participants register (mostly) online. We are converting our most recent, already rescheduled once, event from in-person to on-line (guess why).  Because of the different experience for participants, and the change in expense for us to run an on-line conference, we are considering offering a partial credit to all registrants to use for a future event, while keeping their original registration intact.  We typically do not offer full refunds, but give people the option to transfer their registration to another person, or convert their registration to a donation to our organization. Is there a way in Civi to record this credit?  Is there a way to construct it so that it automatically applies toward the registration fee for the next event they register for?

Comment: did you get anywhere with this Diane?

Comment: I ended up creating custom fields on the registration form to track partial/full refunds/credits, but now I'm thinking it might be easier to track if I create a Financial Type (or types) specifically for these refunds/credits, and only use the custom fields to track specific details for each circumstance.  But this doesn't really address having the ability to have the credit automatically applied to the next event they register for.

Comment: Thanks for responding Diane - i had an enquiry about how folk could cancel and have their fee available to apply to another event it the future. i reckon an extension that is triggered by a cancelled paid registration that creates a cividiscount and emails the person letting them know a discount exists. downside is i think it means adding the discount field to all events which seems to be unnecessary clutter - perhaps i could do it in a way that there is something special in the link they are sent so it all happens invisibly

Comment: Is it possible to have the cancelled paid registration create a pending contribution for a say, Registration Credit financial type?  I would be ok with searching up these people and sending them an email reminding them of the credit when registration for the next big event opens.  But then we'd still have to apply the credit on the backend without the discount code.  And if there was a discount code, we already create an extensive array of discount codes for each event.  How would that discount code be available for any event?